# Valor Null en MySQL con PHP

Tags: php, html, mysql, date

Para insertar datos es utilizado ajax, y aunque a la hora de insertar, funciona correctamente, el problema es cuando se insertan en null.

Cabe señalar que los datos a insertar son de tipo date en la BD.

al insertar un campo vacio, aparece en la BD como 0000:00:00

Como puedo hacer que se inserte ese vslor en NULL?

```js
function insertarIn(){               
    $.ajax({            
        type : 'POST',
        url  : '../indicador/Ininsert.php',
        data: $('#Inform').serialize(),
        cache: false,
        success :  function(data) {                 
            $("#Inresult").html(data).fadeIn();},
        complete: function(){
             setTimeout(function() {
              $('#Inresult').fadeOut();}, 5000);}})};
```

```html
<div id="formulario">  
<center><div id="Inresult"></div></center> 
<form method="POST" id="Inform" >
  <input type="text" name="predio" id="predio" readonly style="display:; ;" >
  <center><label>Inicio proceso</label>
  <input type="text" name="fechaIn" style="margin-top: 12px;" id="fechaIn" readonly></center> 
  <br>
<div class="row">
   
  <div class="col-md-3 col-md-offset-3" style="margin-left: 50px; text-align: justify;">

        <input type="checkbox" name="expediente" id="expediente" onclick="Generacion()" style="margin: 10px 0px 18px 20px" >Generacion de expediente
        <br>

        <input type="checkbox" name="escritura" id="escritura" onclick="Anteproyecto()" style="margin: 10px 0px 18px 20px" > Anteproyecto de escritura
        <br>

        <input type="checkbox" name="rev"  id="rev" onclick="Revision()" style="margin: 10px 0px 18px 20px" >Revisión de expediente
        <br>
        
        <input type="checkbox" name="OAG"  id="OAG" onclick="Solicitud()" style="margin: 10px 0px 18px 20px" >Solicitud OAG y Autorizacion RR
        <br>
        
        <input type="checkbox" name="cheque"  id="cheque" onclick="Elaboracion()" style="margin: 10px 0px 18px 20px" >Solicitud de elaboración de cheque
        <br>
        
        <input type="checkbox" name="pago"  id="pago" onclick="Afectado()" style="margin: 10px 0px 18px 20px" >Pago al afectado
        <br>
        
        <input type="checkbox" name="firma"  id="firma" onclick="Residente()" style="margin: 10px 0px 18px 20px" >Firma del residente
        <br>
        
        <input type="checkbox" name="seg"  id="seg" onclick="Seguimiento()"  style="margin: 10px 0px 18px 20px" >Seg. obtencion de escrituras
        <br>

        <input type="checkbox" name="entrega"  id="entrega" onclick="Operativa()"  style="margin: 10px 0px 18px 20px" >Entrega área operativa
        <br>
 
        </div>

  <div class="col-md-3 col-md-offset-1" style="text-align: justify;">

  <label>fecha recepcion</label>
  <input type="text" name="fechaG"  style="margin-top: 12px;" id="fechaG" readonly>
  <br>

  <label>fecha recepcion</label>
  <input type="text" name="fechaA"  style="margin-top: 12px;" id="fechaA" readonly>
  <br>

  <label>fecha recepcion</label>
  <input type="text" name="fechaR" style="margin-top: 12px;" id="fechaR" readonly>
  <br>

  <label>fecha recepcion</label>
  <input type="text" name="fechaS" style="margin-top: 12px;" id="fechaS" readonly>
  <br>

  <label>fecha recepcion</label>
  <input type="text" name="fechaSo" value="<?php echo $formularioIn['TIND_PROC6']; ?>" style="margin-top: 12px;" id="fechaSo" readonly>
  <br>

  <label>fecha recepcion</label>
  <input type="text" name="fechaP"  style="margin-top: 12px;" id="fechaP" readonly>
  <br>

  <label>fecha recepcion</label>
  <input type="text" name="fechaF"  style="margin-top: 12px;" id="fechaF" readonly>
  <br>

  <label>fecha recepcion</label>
  <input type="text" name="fechaSe"  style="margin-top: 12px;" id="fechaSe" readonly>
  <br>

  <label>fecha recepcion</label>
  <input type="text" name="fechaE" style="margin-top: 12px;" id="fechaSe" readonly>
  <br>
</div>

  <div class="col-md-2 col-md-offset-2" style="text-align: justify;">

  <label>Dias</label>
  <input type="text" name="diaG" id="diaG" style="margin-top:13px; width: 25%" readonly>
  <br>
  
  <label>Dias</label>
  <input type="text" name="diaA" id="diaA" style="margin-top:13px; width: 25%" readonly>
  <br>

  <label>Dias</label>
  <input type="text" name="diaR" id="diaR" style="margin-top:13px; width: 25%"  readonly>
  <br>

  <label>Dias</label>
  <input type="text" name="disS" id="diaS" style="margin-top:13px; width: 25%"  readonly>
  <br>

  <label>Dias</label>
  <input type="text" name="diaSo" id="diaSo" style="margin-top:13px; width: 25%"  readonly>
  <br>

  <label>Dias</label>
  <input type="text" name="diaP" id="diaP" style="margin-top:13px; width: 25%"  readonly>
  <br>

  <label>Dias</label>
  <input type="text" name="disF" id="diaF" style="margin-top:13px; width: 25%"  readonly>
  <br>

  <label>Dias</label>
  <input type="text" name="diaSe" id="diaSe" style="margin-top:13px; width: 25%"  readonly>
  <br>

  <label>Dias</label>
  <input type="text" name="diaE" id="diaE" style="margin-top:13px; width: 25%"  readonly>
  <br>

  </div>

</div>
<center><br>

<label>Justificacion</label><br>
<textarea id="justi" rows="5" cols="80" readonly></textarea><br>

</form>
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>

<?php


require("../conexion.php");

  
 $fechaG= $_POST['fechaG'];
 $fechaE= $_POST['fechaE'];  
 $fechaA= $_POST['fechaA']; 
 $fechaR= $_POST['fechaR']; 
 $fechaS= $_POST['fechaS']; 
 $fechaSo= $_POST['fechaSo']; 
 $fechaP= $_POST['fechaP']; 
 $fechaF= $_POST['fechaF']; 
 $fechaSe= $_POST['fechaSe'];
 $predio= $_POST['predio'];
 $fechaIn= $_POST['fechaIn'];  


$fechaA = !empty($fechaA) ? "'$fechaA'" : "NULL";

     $comprobar="SELECT * FROM tindicador WHERE TIND_IDPRE='$predio';";
     $compro=$mysqli->query($comprobar);
     


      switch ($compro)  {
       case ($compro->num_rows==0):

        $consulta = "INSERT INTO tindicador (
       TIND_IDPRE,TIND_PROC1,TIND_PROC2,TIND_PROC3,TIND_PROC4,TIND_PROC5,TIND_PROC6,TIND_PROC7,TIND_PROC8,TIND_PROC9,TIND_PROC10) 
       VALUES ('$predio','$fechaIn','$fechaG','$fechaA','$fechaR','$fechaS','$fechaSo','$fechaP','$fechaF','$fechaSe','$fechaE');";

       if($resultado = $mysqli->query($consulta)){ 

         echo "<h5 style='color:#06A322;'>Registro guardado correctamente</h5>";

       } else {

         printf("Errormessage: %s\n", $mysqli->error);
       }


        
        break;
       
       case($compro->num_rows>=1):
        
        $consultaD="UPDATE tindicador SET TIND_PROC1='$fechaIn',TIND_PROC2='$fechaG',TIND_PROC3='$fechaA',TIND_PROC4='$fechaR',
           TIND_PROC5='$fechaS',TIND_PROC6='$fechaSo',TIND_PROC7='$fechaP',TIND_PROC8='$fechaF',TIND_PROC9='$fechaSe',
           TIND_PROC10='$fechaE'
          WHERE TIND_IDPRE='$predio';";


       if($resultadoD = $mysqli->query($consultaD)){

        echo "<h5 style='color:#0280BF;'>Registro modificado correctamente</h5>";

       } else {

        echo "<h5 style='color:#A30606;'>Imposible modificar, ocurrio un error</h5>";
          
       }
        break;
      }
     

    $mysqli->close();
    ?>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Si porque si tu campo en la BD lo tienes como DATE automaticamente el interpreta que va a recibir una fecha y por lo tanto si no llega nada coloca 0000:00:00

Comment: estoy al tanto de eso, pero mi pregunta es: Como hacer para quitar ese formato e insertar tipo null

Comment: Edita tu campo en la BD y colocalo texto.

Comment: Al crear la tabla de la base de datos en el campo fecha puedes colocar como defaul value Null.

Comment: Puedes simplemente pasar NULL en lugar de "Null" ya que php lo que interpreta con "NULL" es cadena de texxto y no propiamente un NULL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Gracias a los que participaron.

Aunque intente cada una de las opciones que me escribieron, al final solo la de **Oswell** funcionó... Aunque si existiera otra forma, sin cambiar el tipo date a text, estaré al pendiente

Comment: Esto es una **pésima solución** por varios motivos: se te hará muy dificil controlar datos erróneos, por ejemplo, nada impide que un usuario introduzca una fecha cómo está: `2018/47/80` eso es peor que lo que estás queriendo evitar. Y ... hay más: cuando toque hacer cálculos con las fechas te quiero ver. La mejor forma de hacer lo que quieres es indicando que el campo acepte `NULL` y poniendo por defecto ese valor,  [aquí tienes un ejemplo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1691129/5587982). Nunca cometas el error de **alterar el tipo de dato**, al final lo puedes pagar muy caro.

Answer (score 2):

cambia la estructura de la columna y marca Null.
Pero no pongas un valor predeterminado porque lo rellenara con 0000:00:00

Al realizar un insert simplemente no llames a esa columna  en la sentencia,Mysql guardará directamente el campo como NULL.

O si quieres mantener la columna en tu sentencia hazlo así.

Ejemplo:
Insert into mytabla (columna 1,columna2,col_fecha)
Values ('$valor1','$valor2',null);

Answer (score 1):

En tu base de datos en la estructura de la tabla puedes definir datos predeterminados en caso de que no se inserte nada, ahí puedes incluir el  null, o en su defecto a tu variable definela así $fecha = NULL;, en caso de que no traiga nada.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

tuve el mismo problema y es debido a que si la la variable ej $fecha1=null en la query aparece como espacio vacio; para que resulte se debe colocar $fecha1="null" pero en la query se debe sacar las comillas Ejemplo: Insert into mytabla (col_fecha) Values ($fecha1) y funciona pero cuando se deba pasara un valor como lo pasa como texto en la base de datos queda con 0000-00-00.

**la unica forma que encontre** para solucionarlo es hacer un condicional

```
if(empty($fecha1)){
$sql="Insert into mytabla (col_fecha) Values (NULL)";
}else{
$sql="Insert into mytabla (col_fecha) Values ('$fecha1')";
}
```

Comment: Esto `emmpty` esta mal escrito, va con una m nadamás